# Multiple increment operator in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operators, increment

I'm trying to understand why all following three cases resulted in different output on Visual C++ compiler

**Program 1**

```
  i = 0;
  while ( i < 100)
  {
      printf( "%d: %d\n", array1[i], array2[i]);
      i++;
  }
```

**Program 2**

```
  i = 0;
  while ( i < 100)
  {
      printf( "%d: %d\n", array1[i], array2[i++]);
  }
```

**Program 3**

```
  i = 0;
  while ( i < 100)
  {
      printf( "%d: %d\n", array1[i++], array2[i]);
  }
```

As per my understanding, I was expecting that **increment operator** will increment the value of *i* after the expression has been evaluated. Initially I thought all three would lead to same output but after seeing output, I was expecting atleast **Program 1 and Program 2** output should be same.

However, output was different in all three cases. Please correct me what I am missing here.

Comment: This is invoking undefined behavior, the evaluation order of the function parameters is unspecified. The second problem is that if you modify a variable within a sequence point you are only allowed to read the previous value to determine the new value.

Comment: I was not aware of sequence points. Thanks for pointing to right direction. Marked as dupilicate.